# Como estruturar múltiplos projetos no Git

Tags: git, versionamento, team-foundation-server

Na empresa em que trabalho, usamos o Visual Studio 2013 e o **TFVC** para versionamento dos projetos.

Estou acostumado com o *Source Control Explorer*, poder dar *Get Latest Version* em qualquer nível (todo o repositório, um grupo de projetos, apenas um projeto ou um arquivo específico), criar *Branch* e ver claramente a "pasta" criada com o novo ramo, etc.

A estrutura dos projetos era organizada da seguinte forma:

```
- Repositório
  -- Grupo_de_Projetos_1
     --- Projeto_1
         ---- Development
              ----- Source
                    ...
         ---- Main
              ----- Source
                    ...
         ---- Release
              ----- Source
                    ...
      --- Projeto_2
          ...
      --- Projeto_3
          ...

  -- Grupo_de_Projetos_2
    --- Projeto1
        ...
```

Basicamente com essa estrutura era possível autorizar acesso ao repositório inteiro, a um grupo de projetos ou até mesmo apenas a um projeto específico. Cada projeto era organizado em 3 *Branchs* (Development, Main e Release), todos apenas uma cópia exata. Então os desenvolvedores trabalhavam na `Development` e então podíamos fazer o *Merge* na `Main` para então enviar para a `Release`. Assim, quando surge um *bug* na produção, resolvemos diretamente na `Release`, publicamos e depois replicamos a correção para os outros *Branchs*, e o jogo segue.

Agora foi decidido a mudança para o Git, e fiquei responsável pela migração, mas estou com dificuldades para montar a estrutura de pastas (já consigo entender bem os comandos e muitos conceitos utilizados).

Olhando para minha estrutura antiga no **TFVC**, seria possível criar algo parecido? (Sei que os *Branchs* não serão mais vistos da mesma forma).

Vamos ao checklist:

1. Já tenho meu repositório criado, então ele seria equivalente ao meu primeiro nível da estrutura mostrada anteriormente (-)?
2. Meu Grupo_de_Projetos_1 (--) seria um "subrepositório" ou simplesmente uma pasta? Seria possível configurar níveis de acesso a uma pasta?
3. Cada projeto (---) seria um "subrepositório" também, para poder ser criado os *Branchs* ou simplesmente uma pasta? É possível criar um *Branch* apenas para uma pasta?

> Vi um pouco ainda sobre [submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), seria talvez uma opção nesse
>   contexto?

Fiquei também apaixonado por [essa dica da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668992.aspx), seria possível implementá-la com Git?

Comment: Interessante a pergunta - acredito que cada projeto deveria ter seu repositório né (existe isso de subrepositório?) - Acredito que uma simples pasta num repositório "enorme" não faça sentido para projetos diferentes, principalmente na hora de clonar o repositório e receber um monte de arquivos de outro projeto junto.

Comment: E você conhece [isso aqui](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), né? :D

Comment: Não conhecia não @Blogueira muito obrigado por compartilhar, está sendo uma ótima leitura. (Respondendo a pergunta do subrepositório, o mais próximo que encontrei foi o submodule, mas não sei se é ele quem devo suar nesse caso)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sim, o repositório seria o equivalente ao seu primeiro nível
2. Não! No Git você tem acesso ao repositório inteiro, não dá para baixar apenas uma pasta.
3. Não vejo motivos para você dividir os projetos em repositórios ou sub-repositórios, se eles fizerem parte da mesma Solution, a complexidade só aumentaria. Porém, o uso de módulo é interessante se você tiver uma arquitetura modular, por exemplo, um e-commerce e que em cada módulo da aplicação fique na atuação de um time, vendas, estoque, etc... Você poderia baixar somente os módulo da aplicação pertinentes ao seu trabalho.

É possível você estruturar as pastas no Git como nesta dica da página da Microsoft que você cita. Normalmente eu faço:

- \
- src
- doc
- README.MD

e dentro do src (source), coloco a estrutura da solution, normalmente AS IS como criada pelo Visual Studio.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! O ponto 3 realmente é o meu caso, temos uma arquitetura modular, e separamos cada módulo em uma Solution. Pelo que parece, meu Grupo de Projetos seria meu repositório, e eu poderia dividir cada projeto em um módulo do Git.